# How do I open a PDF file at a specific zoom percentage?

Tags: pdf

Everytime I open a PDF file it opens up in PDF Complete 4.0.9 Special Edition (came pre-installed) at a very high zoom-view (like 274%) and I have to minimize the zoom for EVERY single PDF I open.  The font is always too large to read.  Is there anyway to set-up the PDF program to open up PDF files at a lower zoom permanently?

Also, I have SumatraPDF which I hate cause the search feature doesn't work.  So, please don't suggest using that program.  I want to use programs that are fully functional.  Also, I'm open to buying PDF editors/readers etc. to solve this problem.

Windows 7 64-bit.
IE 8.

Comment: There are many PDF readers out there, Adobe Reader being the first obvious choice. I don't think this question holds much weight on Super User, as it is essentially asking for a list of software.

Comment: But I have 2 PDF readers on my computer and both of them don't solve my problem so how exactly is my question irrelevant?  I just need to know which product: a PDF program or a golden unicorn or whatever anyone is aware of that will solve my issue.

Comment: Get rid of the pre-installed bloatware and Sumatra. Adobe Reader is still the best, and allows you to do what you want (See Tom77's answer). If you don't want Adobe Reader, Foxit is very close and very good (See harrymc's answer). Anything else that reads PDF just plain sucks (in my experience).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [Adobe Reader](http://get.adobe.com/reader/) you can set this as follows:

Edit Menu, Preferences...

Select the **Page Display** category

[image: Adobe Reader Preferences]

From here you can set the default Zoom. Automatic, Fit Width or 100% are probably the best options to try.

Answer (score 4):

My recommendation is the free [Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/addons.php).

This is the fastest PDF reader I know, and Page Display is one of its options in Preferences :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In [Adobe Reader](http://get.adobe.com/reader/) you can select to open documents in **last zoom level** and at **last opened page** under Documents tab:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since **xpdf** is open source, it should be available for windows, too. You can tell it which zoom level to use:

```
   -z zoom
          Set  the initial zoom factor.  A number specifies a zoom percentage, where 100 means 72 dpi.  You
          may also specify ´page', to fit the page to the window size, ´width', to fit the  page  width  to
          the  window  width, or ´height', to fit the page height to the window height.  [config file: ini‐
          tialZoom; or X resource: xpdf.initialZoom]
```

So your starter could include this flag.

> I want to use programs that are fully functional.

I don't know what is meant with that. **xpdf** is very fast, so maybe it isn't.

Comment: Fully functional as in every feature works; SumatraPDF's search feature doesn't actually work.